# Create delegates to generically modify properties/fields whose type is ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, .net-4.7

Let's say I have a simple class like so:

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    public List<SomeOtherClass> ListOfStuff { get; } = new List<SomeOtherClass>();
}
```

`SimpleClass` itself is unimportant, let's say I've interrogated the type and determined it's of interest for some reason, so all I have is the `System.Type` object. Now say that I want to access any non static properties/fields on the class that implement `ICollection<T>` (i.e. `ListOfStuff` on `SimpleClass`). I can access/create instances of `SimpleClass` and I can also dynamically create instances of whatever the collection is made of, but how do I dynamically (and as efficiently as possible) clear or add items to `ListOfStuff`?

Basically I want to be able to create delegates that I can call later that I can pass an instance of the interested type to, and the method will clear a specific property/field on that instance.  Similarly I want another delegate to which I can also pass a instance of the collection's item to (e.g. `SomeOtherClass` in the above example), and it will add it to the collection on the property.

I have the `System.Type` of the class I'm interested in, I have the `PropertyInfo`/`FieldInfo` of the field(s) I'm interested in, and I can create instances of the class and the item used in the collection.

e.g. (this is not real code!)

```
Type type = typeof(SimpleClass);
...
// CreateNew is a method that somehow returns a new instance of a type
object test = CreateNew(type);

// GetCollections somehow returns properties/fields that implement ICollection<>
foreach(var collection in GetCollections(type))
{
    // CreateNewCollectionItem somehow returns a new instance of the item used in the collection
    object newItem = CreateNewCollectionItem(collection);

    // how do I implement these two lines?
    var clear = Delegate.CreateDelegate(...);
    var add = Delegate.CreateDelegate(...);
    ...
    clear(test);
    add(test, newItem);
}
```

How can I make these delegates?

**UPDATE:**
Perhaps I should have said "What's the best/most efficient way to produce these delegates " instead of simply "how". I'm sure I can write some code to do what is necessary, but is there some magic I can use to improve my code? `Expression`s perhaps?

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm creating my instance of the type using `Expression`s and was considering using a `DynamicMethod` or even `TypeBuilder` to create my delegates, as I'm not up to speed on `Expression`s. Does anyone have any guidance/helper classes for these as the code to produce them is not exactly readable...?

Comment: For `CreateNew` you may find https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/ of interest.

Comment: I already have most of the code I need (including `CreateNew`), but thanks!

Comment: Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx to invoke a generic method with types known only at runtime. What about making `SimpleClass<T>`?

Comment: If you do things dynamically, you don't have type safety anyway. So why use generic collections? I don't know if it suits your needs, but why not use the non-generic `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: The classes I'm reflecting on are not mine, but will definitely be generic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType()` to get the interface to `ICollection<T>`, and then reflection to invoke it:

```
var addMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetMethod("Add");
var clearMethod = typeof(ICollection<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetMethod("Clear");

clearMethod.Invoke(collection, new object[0]);
addMethod.Invoke(collection, new object[] { test });
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll add something like this to my tests, I was hoping for something super efficient, but this may be best way.